# Loading and parse xlsx file

Tags: python, django, xlsx

How can I continue working with the downloaded file?
parse it into the model

`views.py`

```
def model_form_upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('home')
else:
    form = DocumentForm()
return render(request, 'core/model_form_upload.html', {
    'form': form
})
```

`my model.py`

```
class Document(models.Model):
description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Parameters(models.Model):
par_time = models.DateTimeField('date')
par_recipe = models.CharField(max_length=200)
par_machine = models.CharField(max_length=200)
par_fa = models.CharField(max_length=200)
par_ag_typ = models.CharField(max_length=200)
par_rollennr = models.IntegerField(default=0)
par_definition_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
par_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
par_value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Used for download Excel files (xlsx). Fields in xlsx are represented as described in the model.

As soon as I didn’t try, I’m new to Django and I’ve got nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a library that reads XLSX files. I find [openpxyl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) the easiest. Install it with `pip install openpyxl`.

To handle uploaded file, write a little function. Something like the the code below.

```
import openpyxl

def handle_parameters_upload(request, file):

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file, read_only=True)
    first_sheet = wb.get_sheet_names()[0]
    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)

    data = []

    # Loop over rows and create `Parameters()` objects with column data
    # row_offset=1 is used if you have a header row in your file, you want to skip it 
    # otherwise use 0 or delete the row_offset parameter, since 0 is default
    for row in ws.iter_rows(row_offset=1):
        parameter = Parameters()
        parameter.par_time = row[0].value
        parameter.par_recipe = row[1].value
        parameter.par_machine = row[2].value
        parameter.par_fa = row[3].value
        parameter.par_ag_typ = row[4].value
        parameter.par_rollennr = row[5].value
        parameter.par_definition_id = row[6].value
        parameter.par_name = row[7].value
        parameter.par_value = row[8].value

        data.append(parameter)

    # Bulk create data
    Parameters.objects.bulk_create(data)

    return True
```

This will open XLSX file, read data from it and save to database. [bulk_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) is used, because it inserts objects in the database in an efficient manner.

Adjust your model_form_upload() view.

```
def model_form_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            handle_file = handle_parameters_upload(request, request.FILES['document'])
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'core/model_form_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

There are also other libraries to read/write XLSX you can use. I often use [pyexcel](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel) as well.

Comment: Borut, and then i can, on the client side, access this data in this way? =) {{obj.Parameters.par_time}}

Comment: Not quite, say you have `objs = Parameters.objects.all()` in you view, you include that in the context and then in template, you loop through objects with `{% for obj in objs %} {{ obj.par_time }} {% endfor %}`. Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something).

Comment: Borut, thanks. And one more question, my file is very large, it will probably take a lot of time?

Comment: Bulk create is the fastest way to save data. With 500,000 rows (about 30 MB file) and on a modern computer it shouldn't take longer than 10-15 seconds to read and save. But it will use quite a lot of memory. If that's the issue, then you'll have to use cursor's copy_from().

Comment: Borut, Apparently I did something wrong, and it didn't work out for me, the page just hung...

Comment: Try with smaller files first. Maybe it just takes a long time to save the data. And setup up [Django logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/logging/) to log errors. A lot of things can go wrong, eg. par_ag_typ might be missing in Excel file and since you don't allow null, database will return error.

Comment: Borut, Many thanks for the logger, I have been looking for a similar solution for a long time.